# await is only valid in async function and async wrap returns undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, sequelize.js, undefined

```
const countUser = await Users.count();
console.log(countUser);
```

Trying to get a count in a database. Th above returns a validity error. The count() is

btw here count() is Sequelize Model.count() method is used to generate and execute a SELECT COUNT SQL query to your connected database

Wrapped it in an async/await like this

```
async function getUsers() {
    const countUser = await Users.count()
    return countUser;
}
```

and it returns as

```
Promise { <pending> }
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `users` AS `users`;
```

and then, wrapped it in another async/await as a promise chain since i thought this might work but no

```
async function getUsers() {
    const countUser = await Users.count()
    return countUser;
}

async function logUsers() {
    const userlog = await getUsers()
    console.log(userlog)
}
```

`console.log(logUsers())` returns same pending error thus the values be undefined.

Any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are not calling `logUsers` inside an async function.

Comment: `logUsers` _also_ needs to be awaited (or you can use a `.then` callback) just the same as `getUsers` did.